# Difference between two compact self adjoint operators

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Let $0\leq A,B:H\to H$ when $H$ is a Hilbert space. I know that $A\leq B \iff B\geq A$ and I have to prove that $\forall n, \lambda_n(B)\geq \lambda_n(A)$ when $\lambda_1(A)\geq \lambda_2(A)\geq...\geq 0$ and the same for $B$.

Comment: Have you considered the [*min-max theorem*](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem)?

Comment: how can I use it?